# How to lock WORD in text-box ASP.NET after pressing space?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have seen many websites that if you write something in text box and press space, the words become locked with a cross mark (X) on right on top ... and when you click cancel the word disappears.

I am having trouble understanding the description, for example of the StackOverflow TAG section when you ask a question page.

How can I achieve this with an ASP.NET text box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't like [**jQuery chosen**](http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/jquery-chosen.php) then try **Manifest**

**[Manifest](https://github.com/jstayton/jquery-manifest)** (License: MIT, [examples](http://justinstayton.com/jquery-manifest/)) also by Justin Stayton enhances text inputs so multiple items can be selected and edited. The API is very consistent with Marco Polo, and Manifest can take a marcoPolo object if autocomplete functionality is required.

```
  $('#recipients').manifest({
      marcoPolo: {
        url: '/contacts/search',
        formatItem: function(data) {
          return '"' + data.name + '" (' + data.email + ')';
        }
      }
    });
```

[image]

The author also points out how these plugins differ from the popular Chosen plugin:

> If you want to make a select element with a lot of options more
>   user-friendly, use Chosen. If you can’t reasonably list out every
>   possible option (like all users in a system), or you need to allow
>   arbitrary values (like new tags), use Manifest.

Source: [DailyJS](http://dailyjs.com/2011/09/20/jquery-roundup/)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Tag It](http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/).

Demo: [Here](http://levycarneiro.com/projects/tag-it/example.html).